# laravel 5.2 pluck function does not work with belongsToMany and key value pairs

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have to models, "mission" and "projects".
In these models I have a belongsToMany Relation.

I get missions with related projects when I select this:

```
$missions = Mission::with('projects')->get();
```

When I wish to select the related project names of the result I do this:

```
$relatedProjects = $missions->pluck('projects.*.name')->unique();
```

I need the * because one mission can be assigned to many projects.
This works fine. I get this collection:

```
Collection {#472
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      0 => "nam"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      0 => "voluptatum"
    ]
  ]
}
```

But If i need the ID of each project too, this does not work:

```
$relatedProjects = $missions->pluck('projects.*.name', 'projects.*.id')->unique();
```

I need a collection like this:

```
Collection {#472
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      1 => "nam"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      2 => "voluptatum"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I got this error:

> ErrorException in Arr.php line 328: Illegal offset type

What can I do?
I need this for this structure:

```
<select name="relatedProjects">
    <option value="$relatedProjects->id">$relatedProjects->name</option>
</select>
```

BTW: this works ...:

```
$array= $missions->pluck('name', 'id');
```

But I want to select unique project names of all the missions with name and id ... not the missions.

I also try this:

```
$array = $missions->toArray();
$relatedProjects = array_pluck($array, 'projects.name', 'projects.slug');
```

But the result is:

```
array:1 [
  "" => null
]
```

the

```
$missions
```

contains the following array:

(after I use the ->toArray() function)

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:19 [
    "id" => 1
    "active" => 0
    "slug" => "sint-repellat-qui-ducimus-placeat-eos-dolorem-harum"
    "name" => "qui"
    "description" => "Unde ad veritatis quia hic."
    "from" => "2016-02-15 02:44:57"
    "to" => "2016-02-15 12:57:22"
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "from_date_time" => "15.02.2016 02:44"
    "to_date_time" => "15.02.2016 12:57"
    "from_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "to_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "from_to_time" => "02:44 - 12:57"
    "formatted_description" => "Unde ad veritatis quia hic."
    "projects" => array:1 [
      0 => array:16 [
        "id" => 5
        "slug" => "et-sint-dolor-voluptatum-dolor"
        "active" => 1
        "name" => "nam"
        "description" => "Ut voluptates quia sapiente cumque et qui."
        "from" => "1977-06-08 09:46:04"
        "to" => "2012-05-30 14:48:15"
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:25"
        "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:25"
        "deleted_at" => null
        "from_date_time" => "08.06.1977"
        "to_date_time" => "30.05.2012"
        "formatted_description" => "Ut voluptates quia sapiente cumque et qui."
        "pivot" => array:4 [
          "mission_id" => 1
          "project_id" => 5
          "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
          "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:19 [
    "id" => 2
    "active" => 1
    "slug" => "vel-consequatur-deserunt-nesciunt-nobis-in-mollitia-explicabo"
    "name" => "voluptas"
    "description" => "Accusantium odio consectetur omnis non doloribus ex."
    "from" => "2016-02-15 03:44:57"
    "to" => "2016-02-15 06:44:57"
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "from_date_time" => "15.02.2016 03:44"
    "to_date_time" => "15.02.2016 06:44"
    "from_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "to_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "from_to_time" => "03:44 - 06:44"
    "formatted_description" => "Accusantium odio consectetur omnis non doloribus ex."
    "projects" => array:1 [
      0 => array:16 [
        "id" => 1
        "slug" => "ab-culpa-provident-laboriosam"
        "active" => 1
        "name" => "voluptatum"
        "description" => "Rerum nam ducimus asperiores eum."
        "from" => "1983-03-23 21:02:04"
        "to" => "1980-02-10 20:08:12"
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:24"
        "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:24"
        "deleted_at" => null
        "from_date_time" => "23.03.1983"
        "to_date_time" => "10.02.1980"
        "formatted_description" => "Rerum nam ducimus asperiores eum."
        "pivot" => array:4 [
          "mission_id" => 2
          "project_id" => 1
          "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
          "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:19 [
    "id" => 6
    "active" => 1
    "slug" => "illum-consequatur-perferendis-fugiat-sit-ut"
    "name" => "quaerat"
    "description" => "Aperiam debitis harum sint."
    "from" => "2016-02-15 05:44:57"
    "to" => "2016-02-15 12:44:57"
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:43"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "from_date_time" => "15.02.2016 05:44"
    "to_date_time" => "15.02.2016 12:44"
    "from_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "to_date" => "15.02.2016"
    "from_to_time" => "05:44 - 12:44"
    "formatted_description" => "Aperiam debitis harum sint."
    "projects" => array:1 [
      0 => array:16 [
        "id" => 1
        "slug" => "ab-culpa-provident-laboriosam"
        "active" => 1
        "name" => "voluptatum"
        "description" => "Rerum nam ducimus asperiores eum."
        "from" => "1983-03-23 21:02:04"
        "to" => "1980-02-10 20:08:12"
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:24"
        "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:24"
        "deleted_at" => null
        "from_date_time" => "23.03.1983"
        "to_date_time" => "10.02.1980"
        "formatted_description" => "Rerum nam ducimus asperiores eum."
        "pivot" => array:4 [
          "mission_id" => 6
          "project_id" => 1
          "created_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
          "updated_at" => "2016-02-12 12:49:45"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: [Considering your error](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.15/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php#L328) you're not running the latest 5.2 - could you try an upgrade?

Comment: I have updated from v5.2.14 to v5.2.15, but no luck. Same error.

Comment: `pluck` doesn't work the way you want it to with a wildcard like `*`.  You have to be explicit with the fields you want (as you've already demonstrated).  You may need to use `lists` with `array_walk` instead.